# How to solve Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist" and W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported" errors?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am getting these "Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"" errors when using camera 2 api in android studio. It does not create some crashes and camera works but still what are these errors and how to solve them?

Also how to solve "W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported" error? 
I have provided logs below.

````
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/le.ocrdetection: type=1400 audit(0.0:5957056): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13808 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
    Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/le.ocrdetection: type=1400 audit(0.0:5957058): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13808 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 2
W/le.ocrdetection: type=1400 audit(0.0:5957059): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13808 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 3
W/le.ocrdetection: type=1400 audit(0.0:5957060): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13808 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 4
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 5
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
    Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 3
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 4
I/Screen: height :2037
    width :1080
D/TextureView: TextureView Width : 1080 TextureView Height : 1440
E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported```
````